# Intersection of points for overlapping polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-join, intersect

I have the following intersection task:

1. I want to do an intersection of points and polygons. I want to add the variables of the polygons to the intersected points
2. Some of the points fall in more than one polygon. It is ok for the polygons to overlap since they are areas of influence.
3. As output, I would like to obtain the intersected points and the variables for all the polygons that intersect with them.
4. If 3 is not possible, I was thinking of duplicating the points that fall in more than one polygon and merge each of them with the information of the polygons.

How should I do this in ArcMap 10.3?

The image below illustrates this issue.

[image: Point that falls within two polygons]

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?  Have you tried the Intersect tool?  If so, did it meet any/all of your requirements?

Comment: ArcMap10.3. I am trying now with the intersect tool. Do I need to specify any parameter to get duplicated points in case it falls in more than one polygon?

Comment: What happened when you tested?  I’d have to either test and/or read the documentation for the tool and don’t have time to volunteer to do that at the moment.

Comment: Another tool worth testing/considering is Spatial Join.

Comment: Thanks, I will try both!